# How to pass parameters (for real) to a CSS class like we do in Javascript?

Tags: css, class, parameters

I'd like to know if there is a way to pass REAL parameters to a CSS class (like we do with Javascript), for example :

In Javascript we are used to write it in this way :

```
&lt;script language="javascript"&gt;
function clWidth(wdt) {
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;document.getElementById('cell').style.width = wdt;
}
&lt;/script language="javascript"&gt;
```

and the input HTML object `&lt;input type="text" id="cell"&gt;` will have the given width.

Now, to have it in the same way but using CSS classes, I'd try something like this :

```
&lt;style&gt;
.clWidth(wdt) {
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;width: wdt;
}

&lt;/style&gt;
```

my HTML objects :

```
&lt;input type="text" class="clWidth(5)"&gt;
&lt;input type="text" class="clWidth(10)"&gt;
&lt;input type="text" class="clWidth(5)"&gt;
&lt;input type="text" class="clWidth(15)"&gt;
```

The purpouse is to have one single class for all the objects which "width" can be given in the object itself, but I can't find the right syntax to use to have this working for good.

I'm already using the multi-classes definition but I really don't like this method because it is not a "programming" way :

```
&lt;style&gt;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.clWidth5  { width:  5px; }
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.clWidth10 { width: 10px; }
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;.clWidth15 { width: 15px; }
&lt;style&gt;
```

I know CSS is not a "programming language" (at least not yet for what I know), but I'd really like to write my code in a better way, using a single CSS class working with real parameters.

If there is a way, please explain me the right syntax to use or else just confirm me that it is not yet supported.

Thank you for any help you can give me to improve my coding.

Comment: You can't pass real dynamic variables to css, but you can create variables with SCSS. It however will still be static, and you will have to define every class individually. You could try CSSNext, to use some of the new syntaxes which do allow dynamic variables, but I am not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: In pure CSS there are a _custom propieties_ https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#funcdef-var. Them have low support in browsers and are very limited, them are not variables. If you want  real variables you have use a prepocesor: SASS, Stylus, LESS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're looking for... Plus, what you want isn't the right way to write css: css is a static language, everything that needs to be dynamic should be achieved in javascript.

In order to achieve that, **but statically**, is to use a `css preprocessor` like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/):

`@each $width in (5, 10, 15, 20) {
  .clWidth-#{$width} { width: #{$width}px; }
}`

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to take parameters from html and use them in css.
However, you can simply writing your css code by using a css extension language like sass or less.

For the example you have given, you can write sass/scss code to simplify your code.

SCSS code:

```
@each $width in (5, 10, 15) {
  .clWidth#{$width} {
    width: #{$width}px; 
  }
}
```

This would compile to in css as:
CSS code:

```
.clWidth5 {
  width: 5px;
}

.clWidth10 {
  width: 10px;
}

.clWidth15 {
  width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: i have no intention to copy your answer @Hitmands. When i started answering, there were even no answers to this post. Looking back now, I find that the answers were similar I agree, but this is a coincidence and i laughed myself finding such a coincidence.